# Getting LiveData to the ViewModel

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewmodel

I would like to access `LiveData` in my `ViewModel`. The problem is that the `LiveData<String?>` requires access to the `activity` in order to be computed. This is how I am computing the `String`.

```
suspend fun Fragment.getAuthToken(): String? {
    val am: AccountManager = AccountManager.get(activity)
    val accounts: Array<out Account> = am.getAccountsByType(getAccountType())
    return accounts.firstOrNull()?.let {
         withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            am.blockingGetAuthToken(it, getAccountType(), true)
        }
    }
}
```

And then computing the `LiveData` from my `fragment` like this:

```
val authTokenLiveData: LiveData<String?> = liveData {
   emit(getAuthToken())
}
```

Kindly, help me get access to the `LiveData` in my `ViewModel` or alternatively tell me how I can compute it from the `ViewModel`.

Comment: You want to compute that inside your view model. I suggest you pass the AccountManager in your view model constructor and make a custom ViewModelProvider.Factory to instantiate it.

Comment: Cool. Thanks. I will do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to find out how to solve the problem thanks to Nicolas.

Step 1. Create a `ViewModelFactory`:

```
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
class AccountViewModelFactory(private val accountManager: AccountManager, private val repository: UserRepository) :
    ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory() {
    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T =
        AccountViewModel(accountManager, repository) as T
}
```

Step 2. Initialize the `ViewModel` from the `Fragment`:

```
private val accountViewModel: AccountViewModel by viewModels {
     AccountViewModelFactory(getAccountManager(), getUserRepository())
}
```

Step 3. Create the `ViewModel` and create the `LiveData` from the `ViewModel`:

```
class AccountViewModel(private val accountManager: AccountManager, private val repository: UserRepository) : ViewModel() {
    val authTokenLiveData: LiveData<String?> = liveData {
        emit(accountManager.myAuthToken())
    }
}
```

Step 4. Create `myAuthToken()` and `getAccountManager()` extension functions.

```
fun Fragment.getAccountManager() : AccountManager = AccountManager.get(activity)

suspend fun AccountManager.myAuthToken(): String? {
    val accounts: Array<out Account> = getAccountsByType(accountType)
    return accounts.firstOrNull()?.let {
         withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            blockingGetAuthToken(it, accountType, true)
        }
    }
}
```